# Elasticsearch Error: SearchPhaseExecutionException: SearchParseException

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch, elasticsearch.js

I am getting the following error when I try and use a template search on an AWS elasticsearch cluster using the query

"match": { "title": "copyright" }

```
Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"match\"{\"title\":\"copyright\"}}]]]; 
nested: Parse Failure [No parser for element [match]]];
```

The query is failing during the search phase, whilst trying to parse the query.

Why is the Parse failing?

My query works fine for a localhost elasticsearch instance.

Here is my mapping for the index type:

```
properties: {
  title: { type: 'string' },
  toc: {
    type: 'nested',
    properties: {
      title:  { type: 'string' },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Please mention the query you are running.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elasticsearch service supports an older version of elasticsearch to the one I was using, 1.5.2, compared to 2.1.
This older version supports a different syntax for template searches, where the **template** attribute is used instead of the **inline** attribute to supply your template, show [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-template.html)